# How to assign a Rails controller value to a JavaScript constant

Tags: javascript, json, ruby, ajax, controller

I have a constant within a JavaScript function that needs to take  a value from a Rails controller or directly from a JSON endpoint.

Here is the controller action that returns the value that I need:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController

def calendar
    client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(client_options)
    client.update!(session[:authorization])
    service = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
    service.authorization = client

  @calendar_list = service.list_calendar_lists.items

  rescue Google::Apis::AuthorizationError
    response = client.refresh!
    session[:authorization] = session[:authorization].merge(response)
    retry
  end
```

This controller action has a corresponding JSON endpoint as well, `localhost:3000/calendar.json`:

This JavaScript is in my application.rb file. I tried passing my `calendarList` constant the instance variable `@calendar_list` but that didn't work.

```
function getEventSources(){
  const calendarList = <%= @calendar_list %>
  const keyArray = calendarList.map(cal => {
  return 'googleCalendarId'
  })

  const calendarIds = calendarList.map(cal => {
  return cal["id"]
  })

  eventSources = []

  for(i=0; i < keyArray.length; i++) {
    var obj = {}
    obj[keyArray[i]] = calendarIds[i]
    eventSources.push(obj);
  }
return eventSources
};
```

This is my `/calendar.json` endpoint:

```
[
  {
    id: "en.usa#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com",
    summary: "Holidays in United States"
  },
  {
    id: "nba_1_%41tlanta+%48awks#sports@group.v.calendar.google.com",
    summary: "Atlanta Hawks"
  }
]
```

Do I need to make some type of AJAX call to retrieve this value or is there a simpler way?

Comment: What is the data type of `calendar_list`? You may be able to do `const calendarList = JSON.parse("<%= @calendar_list.to_json %>")` but yeah, using a JSON API endpoint to get data is the preferred approach

Comment: `calendar_list` is an array of `Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarListEntry` ... I have a calendar.json.jsbuilder file for this endpoint that returns the exact json that my getEventSources function needs.

Comment: When answering questions in a comment, please don't answer in another comment. Instead, edit your question, adding the information into it as if the new information had been there all along, not tacked to the end, and definitely not tagged with "edit" or "update" type tags. Answering in comments forces us to read every comment in the page and try to figure out their order; If we need to know what time something changed we can look at the edit history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved my javascript into a `html.erb` file and out of `application.js`

This is how I passed the controller value to my JavaScript constant

```
const calendarList = <%= raw @event_list %>
```

this did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you either have to surround the embedded Rails variable in single quotes, like

```
'<%= @calendar_list %>'
```

or, if the variable contains an array of objects, which I'm assuming it does since it's described as a list, you have to have JavaScript parse it as a JSON object.

Basically the data from Rails isn't in a format that JavaScript knows how to interpret so you need to format it as a string or object so JavaScript can read it.

Comment: what if i do something like this in the controller 
`@list = @calendar_list.items.map do |c|
      c.id
    end` ; now i have an array called @list that I can assign to my js variable... are you saying javascript doesnt know how to interpret an array?

Comment: I've tried both `const calendarList = <%= @list.to_json %>` and `const calendarList = JSON.parse(<%= @list.to_json %>)` ...no luck

Comment: You're missing quotation marks, try `JSON.parse("<%= @calendar_list.to_json %>")`

Comment: that didn't change anything. I added more details to the original post if that helps